# Android not showing in GRUB menu on a triple boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am using Ubuntu and Windows 10.

I installed Android 7.0 as a third system in my PC and it (Android) was working correctly.

After I restarted my PC, Android is not showing in the GRUB menu. How do I fix it?

Comment: You can try booting Ubuntu and running `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: i done it. but grub setup was not showing android. !!!

Comment: That means your Android wasn't installed in the same way the other were. And I'm not sure if Android for desktop even supports UEFI mode.

Comment: i used android-x86_64-7.1-rc1.iso for installing.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/winapp-android-x86-installer-uefi-t3222483

Comment: cant install android in Pc like as ubuntu , windows  ??

Comment: You need to install all OSes in the same mode if you want Grub to detect all. Android is off topic here, by the way. [android.se] is where you should be.